# Using Percentage Widths

Tags: html, css

I am new to mobile web development and just beginning to learn how to use percentages for the element widths.

I have a div named "blue". Blue has a width of 80% (this is what I was told to do for mobile so that the content never is too wide for the mobile device). Inside of blue I want to have divs named "green", I want to float each "green" div to the lift and display them inline and take up the entire width of "blue".

Do I give the "green" divs percentage widths? How would I keep them square, if the only value I can add is width? Also, how do I calculate in margin and padding if the widths of the "green" divs are percentages?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all (if not all) sizes, margins, paddings, widths, etc can be marked as percentages in CSS. If you have one DIV spanning 80% of the page, you can center it by marking
    margin-left: auto;
and
    margin-right:auto; for that DIV's class or ID.

For nested DIVs, you are once again working with 100% of the parent container. If you mark your child(green) DIV as 100%, it will fill the parent(blue) DIV, not the entire page. You must also include your margin and padding(manually, unfortunately) in this number.

If you have two DIVs floated left, with both having 50% and a 1% margin, you will be at 104% and the second DIV will wrap to the next 'line'. If you then make them 48% width to account for the margin, you will get a 100% fill with margins included.

Comment: Now, if I make the width 48% how do I keep the height the exact same size (so that they are square)?

Comment: I have used a variety of methods for this, but the easiest would be to give its parent DIV a padding-bottom percentage, which will make sure that amount of space is reserved below the child DIVs.

Here is a great, interactive example of doing this for various aspects:
http://jsbin.com/eqeseb/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Setting a element's width to a percentage makes it that wide *relative to its container*. So if you have an inner div inside of an outer div, and you give the inner div a width of 80% and the outer div also has a width of 80%, the inner div will be 80% as wide as the outer div, or 64% as wide as the page.

**NOTE on padding, border, and margin**: these attributes are *in addition to* the CSS width of an element. So if you have an outer div with a padding of 5% and a width of 80%, it will take up 90% of the width of the page.

This is based on experience and may or may not be completely accurate. Please correct me if I am wrong.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVWCu/)

```
.
```